# Sharing browser cookies with an external application like "viewinfileexplorer" feature

Tags: microsoft-edge, webdav

The viewinfileexplorer custom URI scheme offered in MS Edge somehow shares the user's browser cookies with the WebDAV mini redirector - how can we let our own custom URI scheme do this, or is this some first party magic that Microsoft is keeping to itself?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/sharepoint-view-in-edge

Comment: As far as I know, this is impossible. Your application has its own cache, cookie storage, etc. It does not share the browser application's data.